# How to specify default querystring in CAS?

Tags: cas

We have CAS enable application and we need a requirement that when ever we give user id, password and click on submit button, by default it should take a querystring(something like this "service=www.casifiedapp.com").

What could be the better solution? Where do I need to change CAS configuration. I cannot find the the commanline, action urls etc...

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Played with CAS JSP's and found a workaround. 
Write a javascript function in top.jsp(CAS/html/view/default/include/top.jsp) to append service URL as querystring. 
Use this function in CasLoginView.jsp(CAS/html/view/default/CasLoginView.jsp) at onclick event of button.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own AuthenticationHandler to load service data from query string or from another location.

have a look at the docs:
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CAS/How+To+Write+an+AuthenticationHandler